# Laravel 8 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::tabel()

Tags: php, laravel-8

**its laravel 8 course im getting this error while using query builder but with ORM its perfectly run well. when i comment this code and use another method for getting data with query builder in AllCat() method DB::table is running perfectly**

**Category Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Category;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
public function AllCat(){
    $categories = DB::tabel('categories')
    ->join('users','categories.user_id','users.id')
    ->select('categories.*','users.name')
    ->latest()->paginate(5);



  // $categories  = Category::latest()->paginate(5);
  //$categories = DB::table('categories')->latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.category.index',compact('categories'));
}

public function AddCat(Request $request){
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'category_name' => 'required|unique:categories|max:255',
        
    ],
    [
        'category_name.required' => 'Please Input Category Name',
        'category_name.max' => 'Category Less Then 255Chars',
    ]);

    Category::insert([
      'category_name' => $request->category_name,
       'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
       'created_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);

    // $category = new Category;
    // $category->category_name = $request->category_name;
    // $category->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    // $category->save();

    // $data = array();
    // $data['category_name'] = $request->category_name;
    // $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    // DB::table('categories')->insert($data);

     return redirect()->back()->with('success','Category Inserted Successfull');
}


}
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        All Category<b>  </b>
        
        </b>
    </h2>
</x-slot>

<div class="py-12">
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card">
    @if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>{{ session('success') }}</strong>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
    @endif
        <div class="card-header"> All Category 
        </div>
       
    
    
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">SL No</th>
            <th scope="col">Category Name</th>
            <th scope="col">User</th>
            <th scope="col">Created At</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- @php($i = 1) -->
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ $categories->firstItem()+$loop->index }}</th>
            <td>{{ $category->category_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
            <td>
            @if($category->created_at == NULL)
            <span class="text-danger">No Date Set</span>
            @else

            {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($category->created_at)->diffforHumans() }}</td>
            
            @endif
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
        </table>

        {{ $categories->links() }}

        </div>
 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Add Category</div>
        
        <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{ route('store.category') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Category Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="category_name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">

    @error('category_name')
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
    @enderror

 </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Category</button>
</form>
</div>
    </div>
    
    </div>

    </div>



</div>


</div>
```

**Can you tell me what is wrong here**

Comment: `DB::tabel` should be `DB::table` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you sure it is `DB::tabel` and not `DB::table` ?? It surely has to be `DB::table`

Comment: Ohh its spelling mistake hehe thank you so much